# Updating the prototype of ServerRequest in an express/node configuration

Tags: node.js, express

I'd like to augment the prototype of the request object in expressjs, but it isn't clear where this request is defined? I think it is http.ServerRequest, but I can't find that definition either.

What's the right way to do the following...

```
http.ServerRequest.prototype.redirect = function(path) { }
```

Comment: http is a core library in node.js. Your best hope in achieving what you are after might be to use a facade rather than inheritance

Comment: that's what i was afraid of. i was trying to avoid that because it requires all developers to know the name of the new function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express itself adds it's utility methods to `http.IncomingMessage.prototype`, using this pattern [in 2.*](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/e3e7d0def6b26333965b5a55b43d9f34d25b2bb2/lib/request.js#L11):

```
var http = require('http'),
    req = http.IncomingMessage.prototype;

req.foo = function(bar) {
  // Do cool stuff
};
```

And this pattern [in 3.*](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/request.js#L20):

```
var http = require('http');

var req = exports = module.exports = {
  __proto__: http.IncomingMessage.prototype
};
```

It's wise to be careful with monkey patching though, as Vadim Baryshev warns in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Connect framework](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect) and his [middleware libs](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware). Every middleware extends request and response objects after their creation. Changing prototype of core objects not the best way because this can lead to unpredictable behavior in other modules.